# что такое функция Tick?

Tags: unreal-engine-4

я новичок в Unreal Engine,поэтому для меня еще не все понятно.Например функция Tick:
она автоматически создается в исходнике:

```
void ABaseGeometryActor::Tick(float DeltaTime) {
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}
```

У меня возникает вопрос,что за параметры эта функция принимает?что и когда сюда передается?и для чего?

Буду очень благодарен за подробный и ясный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция вызывается на каждое обновление экрана (на каждый фрейм). Если у Вас есть "герой", то он может здесь обновить свои координаты.

Но мы то знаем, что компьютеры бывают разные. Одни быстрые, другие медленные. И количество фреймов в единицу времени будет разное. И если привязываться только к кадру, то на быстрых компах "герой" будет быстрым, а на медленных - медленный. Для этого есть DeltaTime - время, которое прошло с предыдущего кадра (фрейма). И зная скорость героя, можно посчитать, на сколько именно нужно переместить "героя". Да, на медленных компах оно будет рывками, но скорость будет коректная.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: тут принято треугольничек прожимать возле понравившегося ответа.

Comment: буду знать,спасибо!нажал!